# Rubymine, controller file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubymine

So i have this silly problem with RubyMine, i've been working on it for a while and was having great time, but just before i messed something up, and i'm not really able to understand the problem.
When i create normal ruby files, like eg. 'file.rb' it gets recognized, syntax is highligthed, everything works perfect. but when i create very specific controller file i already tried to create but clicked on something, it is recognized as txt, no syntax highlight, no nothing.
I need this controller and it makes me really sad because i can't make it work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RubyMine -> Preferences -> File Types
Then delete filename from the specific list

Comment: really? all of the best programmers i know kept telling me to start using some kind of IDE as quick as possible

Comment: you see in all the conferences the people always use VIM, not rubymine, because though vim is a pain initially but it increaases their productivity. I also used rubymine at first, but i have switched to sublime, but the choice depends on you at the end.